# How to get the time online from actionscript?

Tags: actionscript, time

I need to be able to find the current time from an online source rather than the system to make sure the time is correct. I need to do this in actionscript, preferably 2 rather than 3 though if you have any solution at all post it. Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible reference: http://board.flashkit.com/board/showthread.php?t=663535

The easiest is solution is probably as above, to create a server-side script to return the time and then fetch that in your ActionScript.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the ability to create a server side script, but it was useful response for others.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create an NTP client in ActionScript.  Unfortunately it's been a while since I've done any ActionScript, but here's a straightforward example in Python if anyone wants to do a port: http://maxinbjohn.blog.com/2366141/

Comment: Straight NTP server querying will likely not work, since NTP protocol is based on UDP and you can't create sockets using UDP from ActionScript.